# Prove that if $\det(A) = 1$ or $-1$ and $A$ has all integer entries, then $A^{-1}$ also has all integer entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So this is a home work question I am stuck on:

> Prove that if $\det(A) = 1$ or $-1$ and $A$ has all integer entries, then $A^{-1}$ also has all integer entries.

I would really be grateful of you can help me out.

Comment: You can use $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det A}C^{T}$, where C is the matrix of cofactors of A.

Comment: Hey thanks for the the answer, really appreciated.

Comment: So i would say:    since   A^(-1) = (1/detA)*c^(T), where C is matrix of cofactors of A therefore all the entries are integers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find $A^{-1}$ you have to solve $n$ systems of linear equations, which are summarized in the matrix equation $AX=I$. Using Cramer's rule, you get that the solutions are expressed as fractions whose denominator is $\det A$. If $\det A =\pm 1$, then the solutions are integers.

This is essentially expressing $A^{-1}$ in terms of the cofactor matrix of $A$.

Comment: owe you my life :)